# How to format string to time in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%H:%i:%s') as time
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%T') as time
```

Both results in `NULL`. But why? I don't think the format is incorrect here, but why is my time nor parsed?

```
+------+
| time |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Moreover, I only care for the hours and minutes. But this also fails:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%H:%i') as time
```

My final goal is to create a view, selecting strings from another table and converting them to `TIME` columns:

```
CREATE VIEW
myview AS SELECT
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%H:%i') as time
FROM `othertable`
```

Comment: May we ask why you are storing time-only data in your table?

Comment: No ;) I'm creating a view for an application that forces me to provide a time-only column. My source table is a time as string. Simple as that.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%H:%i:%s')` works

Comment: Not for me on `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27`. The result showing is `NULL`!

Comment: Did you try: `SELECT cast('07:15:00' as time) as time`

Comment: @forpas it works, thanks for the solution. Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: What do your string times look like?  Do they always have hour, minute, and second components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Cast`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) the time strings to `time`:

```
SELECT cast('07:15:00' as time) as time
```

Comment: Note that `'07:15:00'` is already a valid time literal, and no cast at all is necessary to work with it as is.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using version `5.7`.

Look at `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode` if `NO_ZERO_DATE` value returns within the string. [ Btw, `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` parameters are deprecated ]

If you're using Database at `NO_ZERO_DATE`, then `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%H:%i:%s')` or `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:15:00','%T')` returns `null`.

Try to disable that mode by `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` if you have privilege, or you can edit `mysql.cnf` file and restart mysql.

Comment: Indeed `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` is set. While deactivating would work, I'd prefer a solution not having to touch the default mysql settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot disable `NO_ZERO_DATE`, then here is a workaround you may use which still goes through `STR_TO_DATE` to generate time values.  You may concatenate to the time a random date, and then call `TIME()` to extract only the time portion, e.g.

```
SELECT TIME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2019-01-01 ', '07:15:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
--                             ^^ random date  ^^ your time literal
```

Comment: So how can I then trigger the creation of a `TIME` field from a 24h time string, eg during creation of a `VIEW`?

Comment: But if I select just my time string, it will result in a `TEXT` column in a `VIEW`. But I want `TIME` column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your rationale behind `NULL` value seems to contradict [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time), but perhaps section on `sql_mode` `'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE'` can explain the behavior?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-11-05','%Y%m%d') as time
```

try this function

Comment: sorry, the code before was copyed by my local code, it's not a executable code, just edited